# How to trap the Tab Key in a StringGrid?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tstringgrid

I have several components on an FMX form, one of which is a StringGrid. Tab works great inside the StringGrid moving forward one cell at a time. If the Tab Key is pressed from the last column in the last row it jumps out of the StringGrid to the next control on the form.

I'd like to ignore the Tab Key press when the bottom right cell of the StringGrid has focus. Where can I find an example of how to trap the Tab Key in an FMX StringGrid?

Comment: Do the `OnKeyDown`/`OnKeyUp` events not work?

Comment: They do not work. I've tried them.